# Como abrir um arquivo txt que tem um espaço no seu nome python?

Tags: python, arquivo

Estou aprendendo a programar em python e estou com dificuldade em abrir um arquivo em especifico. No caso consigo abrir documentos de texto normalmente, mas quando tem espaço no nome do arquivo ele não localiza o arquivo. Desde já muito grato pela ajuda.

Ex diretorio:
C:\Users\Desktop\Pasta do arquivo\lista telefonica.txt

Estou usando o codigo

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

basedf = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Desktop\Pasta do arquivo\lista telefonica.txt', delimiter="\t", dtype=str)
```

Report recebido pela ferramenta

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File C:\Users\Pasta do arquivo lista telefonica.txt does not exist: 'C:\\Users\\Pasta do arquivo\xlista telefonica.txt
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Notou que no "report", o nome do arquivo não encontrado é "xlista telefonica"?

Comment: Notei sim, na realizado o nome real do arquivo começa com 0201 ARQUIVO e realmente ele substituiu o zero pelo x

Answer (score 3):

O problema não são os espaços - o problema são as barras invertidas `\` que são caracteres de escape. Ponha um prefixo "r" na string do nome do arquivo `r'c:\Users...` ou ponha duas vezes cada barra - como o Python imprime -  para garantir que nenhuma seja expandida para m caractere especial. No caso "\0201" é substituído pelo caractere especial com código octal "0201" queé impresso como "\x81" .

Outra forma de usar é usar sempre barras pra frente "/" em vez de `\` para separar diretórios - que é o caractere usado em todos os sistemas operacionais atuais - o Python aceita essa forma no Windows também.